# What's the use for each of the three different config.xml files in Phonegap 3

Tags: cordova

I've been working with these Phonegap files and can't understand the logic, or the purpose behind them (of having more than one, or two..).

I happen to have three different versions of this file.

in...

```
"platforms/android/assets/www/config.xml"
"platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml"
"www/config.xml"
```

I've been working with the third one, and it worked when changing the Applications' name but it failed when I was updating the icons, to update the icons I had to use the second one, with success.

The thing is I don't get the logical way of using these different files.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you only need to edit www/config.xml then when you build your project using:

```
phonegap build ios
```

it will update config.xml and copy it to those other directories.

However when it comes to icons, it appears that only PhoneapBuild uses the config file, and for building locally you just drop images into the correct folders.

See here for more details:

http://devgirl.org/2013/09/12/phonegap-icons-and-splash-screens-help/

Comment: I understand what your saying. The problem is, that's true only for the file in "platforms/android/assets/www/config.xml" but not for the one in "platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml"